# tinymce : how to convert raw html tags?

Tags: html, tinymce

i used tinymce to allow people to write content. But now i wan't them to edit their own content, i need to use tinymce again.
My problem is in my database, this content is composed of html tags, and when i try to load the text in my tinymce textarea (in edit view), i've got the raw content  eg `<p> Hello my name is <em>John</em> [...] </p>` . But when they written this content, it was with "wysiwyg".

I want to convert this raw html to wysiwig.

here  a screenshot of the raw html

[image]

and i want it to be like this when they click on "edit my content" button :

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, i didnt see anything about 'raw' tag. I won't put it again, thanks for your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
echo <textarea name="icerik" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">'.htmlentities($satir->icerik).'</textarea>;
```

I use "htmlentities" method in php to convert html code to wysiwyg. When you write that converted text between  and , you can get what you want.

Assuming you're using PHP of course. If not, try to search like for example "htmlentities in asp.net" or wait for another answers.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes im using php and twig for views.  I looked for htmlentities's equivalents for twig, and found this `{% autoescape 'js' %}{{ foo}}{% endautoescape %}` . 
And now it works perfectly ! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>html data from your database</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
strip_tags(stripslashes('row html content'))
```